# Dynamic add fields and repopulate all fields with filled data on error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am using Code Igniter for my project, Bootstrap for my CSS

I have a form with an input, that is being captured as an array.
The user is asked to give some points. The user can click on 'Add More' to Add more points. More fields are added to the form when required, using Java Script.

My PHP code is

```
<div class="form-group multi_form_group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="points">Points</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <?php 
        echo form_input (array(
            'id'=>'points',
            'name'=>'points[]',
            'class'=>'form-control',
            'value'=>set_value('points[]')
        ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <a id="add_points">Add More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript is

```
$('#add_points').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().before('<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8"> <div class="has-feedback"> <label class="control-label sr-only">Another Point</label> <input id="point" name="points[]" class="form-control"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback anchor margin-0-5" id="remove_input"></span> </div> </div>');
    });
```

It all works fine and I am able to capture the information in an array.If the form has an error, I want to repopulate the fields with existing details, while displaying the error. I am using codeigniter form helper 'set_value' function for the same.

However, for these array fields, when displaying the form again with error, I am not able to identify the number of items in the points array. So, only the first field is populated with the original data, and all other fields added by javascript is removed. Can anyone help with this.

I am sorry if I am not able to explain properly, but let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

As i don't have enough reputation to post as a comment i'll comment as an answer, but it'll be more like a suggestion anyways.

Since i'm facing the same type of problem soon i've figured out a way to fix this in a view of a javascript since my page does not use PHP.

There's a cool neat feature called localStorage.

```
 localStorage.myValues = JSON.stringify(myValues);
localStorage.fieldCount = JSON.stringify(fieldCount);
//where myValues are values which you've entered and fieldCount is how many
//text fields were dynamically created
```

After displaying your error you could load these values from localStorage:

```
var myValues = localStorage.getItem("myValues") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myValues")) : [];
var fieldCount = localStorage.getItem("fieldCount") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fieldCOunt")) : [];
```

and re-create the amount of fields and populate them with data from myValues.

Edit:

```
function createTFields(amount,divName){ //divname is a parent element
        for (var i = 0; i<amount;i++){
            var newDiv = document.createElement('tr');
            newDiv.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' name='textfield' class='field'> </td>" //assuming it's in some kind of table, remove td in case of not in table
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newDiv);
        }

}
```

Comment: I will need to find out more about the localStorage. But can you help me with how to create the number of fields based on the field count - as it could vary.

Comment: Well, you said you're creating your textfields dynamically and it's assigned to the click of the button. If the error message/page is displayed then somehow you return to the main page. By that return, is it an OK button or whatever, you can call out your function which would take the value from localstorage and create that many text fields.